# Restoring soft_delete using PATCH results in 422 unknown field "_deleted"

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

Playing around with soft_deletes in the python-eve 0.6 and setup a function to restore a delete, but I'm get a 422 (UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY) with the error 
`{"_status": "ERR", "_issues": {"_deleted": "unknown field"}}`

This is the json response from GET

```
{
  "_updated": "Tue, 02 Jun 2015 23:58:50 GMT",
  "_latest_version": 2,
  "_error": {
    "message": "The requested URL was not found on this server.",
    "code": 404
  },
  "title": "Kimberli Dygert",
  "_version": 2,
  "_deleted": true,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "items\/556cdaf4ee67bd0717181826",
      "title": "item"
    }
  },
  "_created": "Mon, 01 Jun 2015 22:21:40 GMT",
  "_status": [
    "ERR"
  ],
  "_id": "556cdaf4ee67bd0717181826",
  "_etag": "d48684051f506ea70590682d1705f18a74faea2f"
}
```

And the function I'm using to try to restore the soft_delete

```
this.restore = function (id, etag) {
    var req = {
        method: 'PATCH',
        url: urlBase + '/' + id,
        headers: {
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'If-Match': etag
        },
        data: { '_deleted': false  }
    };
    return $http(req);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `_etag` or the `_updated` and `_created` fields, `_deleted` is a special meta field managed by Eve. Clients aren't expected to edit the field directly, and you don't need to in order to restore a soft deleted document. Valid PATCH (or PUT) requests made to soft deleted documents automatically restore the document, and Eve updates the `_deleted` field accordingly. Just remove `'_deleted': false` from your PATCH request, and the document will restore as expected.

Comment: For further reference, we have a [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/645#issuecomment-108749432) which originated form this question and will probably lead to an improvement in soft-delete documentation.